# Server not replying message to client in java

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

i am very new to java socket program, I am doing a client server program and encounter some problem on it because my client can't receive the server message,i think the problem is coming out from server and here is the portion of server program that I think consist of mistake

```
if((input.readUTF()) != null){
    output.writeUTF("Welcome my client");  // display the message to client 
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

I am testing my program using the CMD, when I run the client program and I click on the join button(btn1), the "Server : Client connect to " .... "which are/is the" ..... " in server" message is pop out,after that follow by "Server : ....... " you are the\t" ..... " message. When I check my client program,it hang away straight like that.

The " welcome my Client " message should be send back to client and once the client receive the message,it will display more button, I have check many online resource, some of it show that the BufferedReader and PrintWriter is use or wirteBytes/readBytes function. So cant I know where is my mistake ?

http://codepad.org/iw17uwoJ 
This is my client program 
http://codepad.org/oNRohEXp
 This is my server program

Comment: Code in question, please.  Links go stale and so remove all value for future viewers.

Comment: If you're using `readUTf()/writeUTf()` at one end you have to use it at the other end too, not Readers and Writers. NB `readUTF()` does not return null. Why are you testing it?

Comment: so do you mean that I also need a writeUTF at my client side program, because I see that's something absence in my program and my client can't publish the server output?

Comment: What part of 'you have to use it at the other end too' don't you understand?

Answer (score -1):

To get response from client side to the Server side data will be send from client side. Add simple code in client side MyNoteCenter.java class.

```
try
    {
      Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
      DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
      DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());    
      output.writeUTF(tf1.getText() + " & " + tf2.getText());
      String word = input.readUTF(); 
      System.out.println("word=" + word);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word);    
      output.flush();
      output.close();
      s.close();

    }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Client : Can't Connect To Server, Please Try Again");
        }
```

Comment: hi,rafiq, I try to change my code according to your advise but it still din't give me any response. Do I need to show you my code after changing was make ? I am not sure bout it

Comment: I check your code. There is no problem. At first run server then run client.

Comment: Enter username and id in the client Panel and then click join.

Comment: thank you, you are so nice, you totally solve my problem. I learn something new, god bless you

Comment: Q. How would `word` ever be null? A. It can't. Part of this code is therefore unreachable, and therefore untested.